# Why does PyPDF2 disable clickable checkboxes in PDF form

Tags: python, pdf, checkbox, pypdf

We are working on internal project in our company in which we are willing to automate filling the form for posting workers on projects abroad. We are automating filling our company and employees details, which went successfully. In the next step we will input data manually - ticking checkboxes, input dates, input data about turnovers and structure of projects, company, employees.

```
###Sixth working attempt - for all pages filling text fields with values from employees and company database

import pandas as pd
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
import pandas.io.sql as psql

writer = PdfWriter()
reader = PdfReader("/Users/rob/Downloads/23092021-VP-3+-+Žiadosť+o+vystavenie+prenosného+dokumentu+A1+z+dôvodu+vyslania+zamestnanca+na+územie+iného+členského+štátu+EÚ.pdf")
fields = reader.get_fields()
#x = fields.items()

count = -2
for j in range(len(reader.pages)):
    page = reader.pages[j]
    fields = reader.get_fields()
    
    writer.add_page(page)

    
    for i in fields.keys():
        if "Text" in i and count in range(8):
            writer.update_page_form_field_values(
                writer.pages[j], {i:f"{company_data.iloc[count][1]}"}
            )

        elif "Text" in i and count in range(8,23):
            writer.update_page_form_field_values(
            writer.pages[j], {i: f"{df.iloc[5][count-8]}"}
            )
            print("First condition met")   

        elif "Text" in i and count in range(23,26):
            if df.iloc[5][6] == "Slovenská":
                writer.update_page_form_field_values(
                writer.pages[j], {i: f"-"}
                )
            else:
                writer.update_page_form_field_values(
                writer.pages[j], {i: f"input manually"}
                )
        
        else:
            writer.update_page_form_field_values(
            writer.pages[j], {i: f"test {i} "}
            )
        count += 1

        

# write "output" to PyPDF2-output.pdf
with open("filled-out.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)
```

The problem we are dealing with is that the output PDF file, which we get, simply does not allow us to click on checboxes, although we still are able to edit text in text fields which we already filled with PyPDF2 library in Python. If someone experienced with Python PDF forms filling automation I will appreciate your suggestins. I have been googling solution for hours last days with no success and PyPDF2 documentation does not seem to provide solution as well. Thank you!

pdf form https://www.socpoist.sk/api/idsp/download/cc10770f-2166-45b6-a4c4-60423faec92a on website of national social insurance institution https://www.socpoist.sk/.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is that type of Adobe XFA (proprietary Xtended Forms = less standard) already set secured to be signed twice file. Others such as AcroForms should fare better.

If the file is modified, without simple user save manual entry, it will self-adjust to throw an error warning.

***"This document enabled extended features in Adobe Reader. The document has been changed since it was

created and use of extended features is no longer available. Please contact the author for the original

version of this document."***

[image]

You could possibly bulk load data via standard xfdf methods but depends on what is doing the import and export (It should work in Adobe Pro ?)
Usually in cases where bulk entry is expected the issuing Authority provide a template and guide for automatic entries, sometimes a JavaScript combined with an xml layout.

The whole point of restricting to manual entry is

> I declare that the information given in this application is true and I have not concealed any facts. ...... Changes that occur during this time, I will notify
> in writing within ten days to the relevant branch of the Social Insurance Agency by means of a "Notification
> of the employer and the employee of changes which have occurred during the period of posting'.

In other words it is not designed for Automated adjustment or entry.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thank you! We will try to figure something out.